# What's wrong with self-answering while adding information missing in the original question?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, self-answer

So, if you look at the edit history of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360046/net-runtime-error-80131506-passing-lamda-to-native-function/52360307#52360307) you'll see that I originally thought my problem lay with the `Process` object that I was wrapping. So that was the only code I provided.

Upon further investigation I found that the issue actually lay with the way I was calling a native method via a static wrapper (nothing I could do debug wise led me to this due to the nature of the crash, a more experienced dev helped me).

Consequently, I posted an answer with the correct solution.

This was subsequently closed for being "backwards" and therefore "not useful". This confuses me as between them, my Q&A contained all of the information necessary to fix this bug (which incidentally seems to have multiple causes and fixes). Thus, it would appear to be inherently useful. I also couldn't find this particular solution on any of the other similar questions.

On advice of more experienced users, I've rearranged the Q&A but now it doesn't actually reflect the question I was originally asking and implies a greater standard of initial knowledge than was present. Hopefully, this question will now be reopened.

I fail to see how this improves the utility of the question. Could someone please explain why it is supposedly considered so important that additional information pertinent to the question isn't placed in a correct answer but instead the question is editted?

Comment: Well, I guess that the Q. should have been closed as a dupe of some canonical 'do not destroy objects, (or allow them to be destroyed), before their design lifetime is over'.  If such a target does not exist, it probably shoud, since the issue is quite common with multiple threads:(  Prolly got hit with 'not useful' to avoid the effort of dupe lookup.

Comment: @Martin That may or may not be true, but I think that it is only tangential to the question asked here. Referring to the merits of the linked posts only makes the meta effect stronger, and since you've already expressed your dislike of the meta effect in the past; maybe you should not worry about the linked example, but about the specifics of the question posted here, IMO.

Comment: This has come up before. The dilemma where the information being missing is the *reason* for the question's existence - putting the information in the question is tantamount to erasing or defeating the question entirely.

Comment: @BoltClock I think there's an important distinction to make between a "Hail Mary" question - where I ask something like "my giant multithreaded application in FworbleScript# crashes roughly once every 30 hours with this cryptic error message and no traceback; does anybody have any idea what the cause could be or how I could even start debugging?" - and a mundane mistake that's findable by ordinary debugging techniques but where the relevant code hasn't been included. In the former case, I agree with you; the *latter* case is exactly what the MCVE close reason is for.

Comment: @BoltClock (To be clear, I don't know enough about the tech stack being used to judge how to categorise *this* particular question; I'm just speaking in generalities. Also, here's an example of my favourite Hail Mary answer I ever wrote, for those who don't understand BoltClock's point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24598848/1709587. It'd be patently unreasonable in that case to expect the asker to recognise what details of their environment were relevant in order to include them in the question without already knowing the answer, and the question is still useful without those details.)

Comment: Selfie Q/A can be rather counter-intuitive, you may be better off just starting a personal blog instead. Unfortunately, SO just isn't set up for selfie Q/A contributions in the form of "Here's a strange bug I just encountered, I fixed it! Here's how!", it's also rather poorly set up for "I couldn't find sample code for how to do X so I'll just write some here!". It takes a lot of work to go from that discovery to something that will succeed on SO; too much work, IMO.

Comment: @jrh in fairness, I was waiting for an answer and solved it in the meantime. I didn't plan on it being a self answer

Answer (score 32):

Questions need to be **complete**.

That's the reason we have the "non-reproducible" close reason (*"backwards"* is not a close reason).

And in the same way than posting new answers within the question doesn't work, posting new questions (or information required for the existing question to be answerable) inside the answer doesn't work either.

If the answerers do not have all the information **in the question**, they obviously can't answer. Reading existing answers *shouldn't be required to post a new answer* (beyond making sure you are not posting a duplicated answer, obviously).

And for users looking for a solution, if you do not describe your problem fully, how are they to know they have the same problem as you?

It's nice that you were able to post an answer to your own problem, but since in the process you realized important information was missing in the question, your options were either to **edit the missing information, edit it so it was clear the question was *about* the missing information,  or simply delete it**, since as it were the question wasn't answerable by anyone who wasn't you.

Since you have edited your question, it already have accrued two reopen votes (so far). So things seem to be working as they should. :)

Answer (score 8):

StackOverflow is a "solution search engine", kind of.

So users with a problem with `A` will look for `A`, or `A problem`, and expect to find solutions to a problem with `A`. And users with a problem with `B` will look for `B` or `B problem` etc.
Same-wise, users with knowledge about `A` will look into questions about `A` and try their best to provide solutions to `A` problems, and users with knowledge about `B` will try to answer `B` questions with solutions for `B` problems.

Now you asked a question about `A problem`, and it turns out your problem was not with `A`, but `B`. So you posted an answer with a solution to `B problem`.
What's wrong with that? Well:

- Your question is not useful to users with `A` problems, because the solution provided is not for `A` problems but for `B` problems.
- Your question was not useful for people knowledgeable in `A`, either, since your actual problem was not with `A`. So experts in `A` problems actually wasted their time by looking at your question.
- Your question is not useful to users with `B` problems either, because you don't mention `B` in the question, the question is about `A` problems, so people looking for solutions to `B` problems won't even look at your question about `A` problems (and they won't have an easy time finding your answer about `B` problems, either).
- Your question was also not useful for people with knowledge about `B` problems, because they didn't even know that it was actually a `B` problem instead of an `A` problem. They won't improve your answer nor propose their own solutions because the question is not about `B` problems.

See why your question was "backwards" and deemed not useful enough to remain open?

Now, you say that you edited it and included the actual problem etc. so that probably will be enough for it to be reopened. Next time remember to edit the question into the actual problem before posting an answer to it.

Comment: Very thorough.  Perhaps it could simply be summarized as "The **answer did not match the original question** and so it would not help another programmer who searches for that question.  Instead, they would find an answer to another problem only realized after corrected debugging."